# pg_auto_failover Installation fails on Rocky linux

Tags: citus

I want to install pg_auto_failover(https://github.com/citusdata/pg_auto_failover) on rocky linux 8.5 .
But when I key in the following install command:

(1) curl https://install.citusdata.com/community/rpm.sh | sudo bash

the console shows the error message: Detected operating system as rocky/8. Unfortunately, your operating system distribution and version are not supported by this script.

(2) sudo yum install -y pg-auto-failover10_11

the console shows the error message: No match for argument: pg-auto-failover10_11 Error: Unable to find a match: pg-auto-failover10_11

I wonder if there is any possible way to install pg_auto_failover on Rocky linux 8.5 or above.

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You can either open an issue in pg_auto_failover repo to request package support for this OS, or try building pg_auto_failover by yourself.